# How to create try-finally method for ASP.Net Core 6 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In previous versions of .Net Core, we had a `public static void Main(string[] args)` method in `program.cs`. In this method we could use a `try-(catch)-finally` block, where the `finally` is executed when the application is closed.

In .Net Core 6 has the program.cs changed and there is no `Main()` method anymore. How to create a 'finally method' that is executed once the applications stops/closes.

I tried to do it right away in program.cs, but then the `finally`-block is executed immediately.

**Example (dummy) code program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

SomeAPI _someAPI = CreateSomeAPI();

try
{
    _someAPI.Connect();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception was throw {0}", ex.Message));
}
finally
{
    _someAPI.Disconnect();
}

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Comment: You can create a `Main` method if you still need one.

Comment: It is just syntactic sugar. You can still create a Program.cs and Startup.cs with a `public static void Main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole app initialization code should be wrapped in the `try` statement

```cs
SomeAPI _someAPI = CreateSomeAPI();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    _someAPI.Connect();

    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception was throw {0}", ex.Message));
}
finally
{
    _someAPI.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but when I try, I never reach the `finally` block

Comment: Terminate the process from command line (`CTRL + C`) and you will see that `finally` is reached. Even in previous .Net Core versions it wouldn't be reached when you stop the application from visual studio because in that case the process is killed.